# .change not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<td style="border:#999 solid thin; background-color:#000; color:#FFF;" id="tp">00.00</td>

<td style="border:#999 solid thin; background-color:#000; color:#FFF;" id="tv">00.00</td>
```

When the #tp value changes this value should be reflected in #tv

My Code

```
$('#tp').change(function() {
     $('#tv').text($('#tp').text());
 });
```

What exactly is wrong here.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table cell doesn't have a `change` event. Only input elements have that.

You could

- try manually triggering the event when you alter the cell's content `$('#tp').change();` no idea whether this works across browsers, you'd have to test
- put a transparent, unclickable `input` element into the cell and put the change event on that
- Alter both cells from within whatever script changes the one cell, and not rely on the `change` functionality at all

Comment: I could not change the code, since it was beyond 10K, so I had to add another 400 lines :D

Answer (score 0):

Here tp values changes means how and when? Are you binding change event to your element after its value is being changed? 
Also not "The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements." **[Ref](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**

Answer (score 0):

as you can read in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element
>   when its value changes. This event is
>   limited to  elements,
>    boxes and 
>   elements. [...]

so, if you realy wan't to do this, you have to periodically look at the value and see if it has changes "by hand". (or simply call `$('#tv').text($('#tp').text());` in an interval -  but that will cause a lot of unnecessary updates). the best way would be to update your second value at the same place where you update the first one.